# Image view (Titanium)

Tags: android, imageview, titanium

I am trying creating remember `checkbox` using image view with following code and is working fine for `ios` even in android the if else statements are working fine but

```
 remember_me.image = 'images/buttons/checkbox_not_ticked.png';'
```

is working only once in android if i click it again its not changing the image from ticked to `unticked`. Please suggest bug

```
ar remember_me = Titanium.UI.createImageView({
      image:'images/buttons/checkbox_not_ticked.png',
      width:Ti.UI.SIZE,
      height:Ti.UI.SIZE,
      left:20
    });
    row2.add(remember_me);
    row2.add(remember_me_label);


    remember_me.addEventListener('singletap', function(e) {

        if(!remember_me_var)
        {
            remember_me_var = true;
            remember_me.image = 'images/buttons/checkbox_ticked.png';
        }
       else
       {
            remember_me_var = false;
            remember_me.image = '';
            remember_me.image = 'images/buttons/checkbox_not_ticked.png';
       }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The appcelerator titanium has encountered the problem while double clicking on the image view.This has been already reported [here](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-10342). You can solve this problem by using a view instead of imageview. I have also faced this problem and I solved it using view.

```
 var remember_me = Titanium.UI.createView({
       backgroundImage:'images/buttons/checkbox_not_ticked.png',
       width:Ti.UI.SIZE,
       height:Ti.UI.SIZE,
       left:20
    });
    row2.add(remember_me);
    row2.add(remember_me_label);

    //Click event can be used instead of singletap. Singletap also fires click event
    //Changing the image while clicking on the image
    remember_me.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
       if(!remember_me_var)
       {
          remember_me_var = true;
          remember_me.backgroundImage = 'images/buttons/checkbox_ticked.png';
       }
       else
       {
          remember_me_var = false;
          remember_me.backgroundImage = 'images/buttons/checkbox_not_ticked.png';
       }
    });
```

Hope this will solve your problem. Happy Programming:)

Answer (score -1):

Rather than doing it programmatically I would suggest using a selector drawable to define the on/off state of your CheckBox:

checkbox.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_ticked" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_not_ticked" />
</selector>
```

You can then add the `android:button=@drawable/checkbox` to your widget. This worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Sorry kent I am not developing this using native anroid development. I am using appcelerator for this. Do you have any idea how to solve this using appcelerator

Comment: Sorry but I have only ever used Eclipse for Android development.